# changing QMovie object inside a QGraphicsScene in response to KeyEvent

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene

I searched in the internet for a while but couldn't find any proper answer. Does anyone know how to change the movie in a QMovie object inside a QGraphicsScene in response to a keyEvent ? I tried using setMovie and also tried stopping the movie before changing the movie and then start the movie again, but it didn't really work, the movie item just disappears after a key event

```
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QLabel>
#include "player.h"
#include "weapons.h"

Player::Player(qreal playerSize, QGraphicsScene *gameScene){

    //transparent background

    this->QLabel::setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);

    //Draw the player

    this->setGeometry((gameScene->width()-playerSize)/2,(gameScene->height()-playerSize)/2,playerSize,playerSize);

    setCurrentAnimation(IDLE_LEFT);
    this->movie()->setScaledSize(this->size());
    this->movie()->start();
}

//set Current animation

void Player::setCurrentAnimation(int animationCode)
{
    curr_Animation_Code = animationCode;
    switch(animationCode)
    {
        case IDLE_LEFT  : this->setMovie(new QMovie(":/player/Laura/idle_left.gif"));break;
        case IDLE_RIGHT : this->setMovie(new QMovie(":/player/Laura/idle_right.gif"));break;
        case RUN_LEFT   : this->setMovie(new QMovie(":/player/Laura/run_left.gif"));break;
        case RUN_RIGHT  : this->setMovie(new QMovie(":/player/Laura/run_right.gif"));break;
    }
}

void Player::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event){
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Left){
        this->setGeometry(x()-10,y(),this->width(),this->height());
        if(curr_Animation_Code != RUN_LEFT)
        {
            this->movie()->stop();
            setCurrentAnimation(RUN_LEFT);
            this->movie()->start();
        }
    }
    else if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Right){
        this->setGeometry(x()+10,y(),this->width(),this->height());
        if(curr_Animation_Code != RUN_RIGHT)
        {
            this->movie()->stop();
            setCurrentAnimation(RUN_RIGHT);
            this->movie()->start();
        }
    }
}
```

//QGraphicsScene Snippet

```
gameScene = new QGraphicsScene();
gameView = new QGraphicsView();

setSceneBackground(first_room->getRoomCode());
gameScene->setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QImage(*currentRoomBackground).scaled(mainWindow->width(),mainWindow->height(),Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,Qt::SmoothTransformation)));
gameScene->setSceneRect(0,0,mainWindow->width(),mainWindow->height());

Player *player = new Player(80, gameScene);
gameScene->addWidget(player);
player->setFocus();
```

Comment: could provide a [mcve] of your code to check what the error is and so you learn more.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: I have tested your code and it works well, in the following link is my test code: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/49055538

Comment: Does the player animation change if you press the arrow keys?  because in my case the player still disappears if I press the arrow keys.

Comment: Test my code, and tell me if it works for you.

Comment: I tested your code, it didn't work for me

Comment: And I noticed that the code works fine as long as I don't try to change the QMovie

Comment: I finally figured it out... what actually happened was that everytime  I change the gif file, the Qmovie size changes to the size of the new gif file and goes out of the the window making it look like as if it disappears. Now I added a statement to resize the QMovie size everytime I change the gif file and it works fine now.